# Get number of likes on a facebook profile picture (graph api)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of Facebook userid-s.
I would like to get the number of likes on their profile picture via Graph API.

Something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$userid/picture/likes
```

It's not working (obviously :-))... Unfortunately I can't find anything about this on the Graph API documentation, either. Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much!

Tomi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following FQL query:

```
select pid, like_info.like_count from photo where aid in (select aid from album where owner = me() and name='Profile Pictures') and position = 0
```

Comment: As of August 8 2016 FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried. With the Graph API you can only get the like count for a photo (also profile pic) if you have the user_photos authorization.