# Facebook user profile picture likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get a list of people going to an event, and so I have their facebook id. With that ID I can get there [profile picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture):

```
/v2.7/{user-id}/picture
```

This gives me a link to their profile picture. But now I want to know how many likes this profile picture has. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654400/get-number-of-likes-on-a-facebook-profile-picture-graph-api), but it was for FQL, which is now deprecated.

If I could get the facebook ID for the profile picture, I could use [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/) to get the number of likes.

I'm using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to test my queries.

Comment: Of course that is not possible

Comment: You mean because of privacy concerns? Because it was possible with FQL

Comment: Yes because of privacy concerns. FQL doesn't exists anymore so what was impossible doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spoken to a Facebook engineer: it's not possible. Case closed.